# Running a program at login as admin

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a program I wrote in Visual Basic Express 2013 to put a classification banner at the top of the screen.  I set up a scheduled task using ngen.exe which makes it run at login.  The problem is that it doesn't run as admin so any non-privileged user can kill the task.

This program is to replace another program called Netbanner because there are a few issues with Netbanner.  The program I wrote resolves all of these issues except for the admin issue.  Netbanner is implemented exactly the same way (ngen.exe) but it won't let a non-privileged user kill the task.

I don't know if it is something in the program itself or I missed something in the deployment process.

This is the command used to deploy Netbanner which I duplicated to deploy mine:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\NetBanner\NetBanner.exe"

Also, these are the files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft\NetBanner:

```
NetBanner.exe
NetBanner.InstallState
NetBanner.pdb
NetBannerSchTask.xml
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go into the properties->Compatibility->Run this program as an administrator for the application.

Alternatively, you could do the same thing for a batch file that you can schedule to run on startup.

Comment: This has to be deployed to 700+ computers and it has to be run when the user logs in.  Not sure how this would help.